# Aprilaire 600M wiring help

Tags: hvac, humidifier

I'm new to the forum and I noticed that this is the place where people ask for tips and instructions with anything to do with HVAC... I figured I would give it a shot since it seems everyone is helpful from the previous threads I have viewed.

I have a brand new Carrier furnace with a 24V HUM outlet and a 600M Aprilaire humidifier.

The diagrams that come with the instructions are either for using a transformer because of a 120V furnace circuit board or for a 600Automatic.

I have split the wire that comes with the unit and plugged the red in the HUM outlet and the white in the C port on the furnace. From there I went to the humidistat, split the red and wired each red end to the 2 screws. The white is whole. From there both the red and white continue to the water solenoid. I split the wire and connected the red to 1 end and the white wire to the other end.

To me this seems like how the wiring should be done based on some diagrams I have viewed however its not working so I'm wondering if anyone has any tips or can point out what I did wrong.

Comment: What is the model of your furnace? It's not clear what a "humidifier outlet" is.   If it is simply a 24V power source for the humidifier, the wiring is simple and you should follow the instructions, simply using the "outlet" in place of the transformer.  Also, the instructions refer to two yellow wires ... is that what you mean by "one end" and the "other end"?  And, what does "split the wire" mean?   Your question could be made a lot clearer by using words and descriptions from the manual, and describing how you don't understand them or need to apply things differently.

Comment: I was trying to use basic, simple words. But I figured out what the issue was.... The wiring of the 2 whites at the water solenoid broke/discinnected which was causing the issue.    I appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: @syncmastet -- post that as your answer and I'll give you a +1 :)